# Could someone explain what the following SQL query does?

Tags: sql

I have my suspicions but I want to independently verify, what does this query do? It's for a mybb forum database:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mybb_users LIKE 'unreadpms'
```

For clarification, I'm asking if this is a query to view all users' unread PMs (the suspicious part)? I know it seems 'Captain Obvious' but I'm attempting to "independently verify" "my suspicions".

Comment: Amazingly insightful stack overflow is. Or perhaps it's a query to view all unreadpms of mybb_users on a forum, which from a privacy and security perspective would be highly questionable. Of course I was hoping someone would suggest that without my saying it so I could "independently verify" "my suspicions".

Comment: `"Of course I was hoping ..."` - If there was something specific you were trying to learn, perhaps you could have asked that?  Nobody here can read your mind.  The query *shows the columns*.  The code is pretty clear about that.

Comment: Note: There's also handy documentation regarding this query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Comment: I wanted to see if anyone else arrived at the conclusion without my suggesting it to see if it was a reasonable conclusion to make. I want to know if this query is designed to view every forum users' (unread) PMs, and if such a query would be considered unusual for a mybb forum. My concern is someone is running a query to view people's unread PMs. [a security/privacy issue but I have to confirm the original premise first]

Comment: How about you just read the documentation? Why would you even suggest it has anything to do with reading unread PM's for a user? (And how would that be inherently insecure? People query for their unread PM's all the time.) You've shown no effort and don't even bother asking us to verify your opinion, because you don't give us your analysis. As such, it's off-topic.

Comment: @c1646091: Your analysis in that last comment demonstrates a *complete* lack of understanding of how relational databases (specifically MySQL) work.  We can sympathize with the fact that you have no experience in the matter, not everybody is an expert.  But given the fact that you don't know anything about MySQL *at all*, perhaps your concerns are *slightly* unfounded?  Instead of trolling Stack Overflow, you might want to start with some MySQL tutorials and documentation.

Comment: You clearly forgot to read the documentation. Not knowing SQL is fine; not even *trying*, and then when you're spoon-fed the answer you *still* don't believe-indicating you *still* didn't read the docs even when a link is provided, means you don't even care. The pain in the butt isn't SO, which did your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As the semantics of the code suggest, it [shows columns from a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html).

From the documentation, an example would be:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM City;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Whatever columns are in `mybb_users` which match the filter `LIKE 'unreadpms'` would be returned in a similar format.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to infer it's a query to view all users' unread PMs?

Comment: @c1646091: I certainly wouldn't infer that.  Unless users' unread PMs are being stored in the actual *column names* somehow?  I wouldn't consider that to be a reasonable database design.

Comment: Not the actual contents per se, but a list of unread PMs (IE their titles)? Surely it has to be pulling up something from everybody's unread PMs and I'm trying to determine if this purpose is suspicious or innocuous, because it could very well be an SQL capable admin digging through people's personal messages.

Comment: @c1646091 Of course not, unless the person doing the inferring knows nothing about MySQL and can't read documentation, in which case their inference holds no weight and is irrelevant.

Comment: @c1646091 ... The answer shows sample output. Read the docs. Run it. "Surely"? Why? If you're not even going to believe what people say, why even bother asking?

Comment: @c1646091: So... If your question is, "Is my understanding of this query correct?"  Then the answer is, "No.  Not at all.  Not even close."

Comment: You insist the line "unreadpms" does NOT indicate the extraction of data involving unread PMs? I just don't buy that, and the patronising attitude of yours from start to finish doesn't help. Clearly I was mistaken about stack overflow. I'll take the query elsewhere.

Comment: You "don't buy that"?!?! @c1646091 Why did you even bother asking this question, then? The docs tell you what the command does. Someone answered you in good faith. And you don't "buy it"? Yes, please, take your query elsewhere. (Hint: the answer will be the same. Come on: the output of the command is shown in the answer.)